# Induction: Show that $\sin(2x) + \sin(4x) + \ldots+ \sin(2nx) = \frac{\sin(nx)\sin((n+1)x)}{\sin(x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, induction

> Show that $\sin(2x) + \sin(4x) + \ldots+ \sin(2nx) = \dfrac{\sin(nx)\sin((n+1)x)}{\sin(x)}$

I tried to use induction.

Base case is easy, but I'm stuck at the induction step (from $k$ to $k+1$). So I have:

$$
\sin(2x) + \sin(4x) + \ldots + \sin(2kx) + \sin(2(k+1)x)\\
 = \frac{\sin(kx)\sin((k+1)x) + \sin(x)\sin((k+2)x)}{\sin(x)}
$$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Do you mean
$$\sin(2x) + \sin(4x) + \ldots + \sin(2kx) + \sin(2(k+1)x) = {\sin((k+1)x)\sin((k+2)x)\over\sin(x)}$$?

Comment: What is your base case? Presumably not $0$, since $\frac {0}{0}$ is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Umm....wouldn't it be easier to use complex numbers. Take $z=e^{i2x}$ and add the series $z+z^2+z^3+...+z^{2(k+1)x}$, which is a G.P. series hence find the sum and equate the imaginary part....

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\sum_{1\le r\le n}\sin 2rx=\frac{\sin nx\sin(n+1)x}{\sin x}$$

$$\implies \sum_{1\le r\le n+1}\sin 2rx=\frac{\sin nx\sin(n+1)x}{\sin x}+\sin2(n+1)x=\frac{2\sin nx\sin(n+1)x+2\sin2(n+1)x\sin x}{2\sin x}$$

Applying $\displaystyle2\sin A\sin B=\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)$

$\displaystyle2\sin nx\sin(n+1)x+2\sin2(n+1)x\sin x$

$\displaystyle=\cos x-\cos(2n+1)x+\cos(2n+1)x-\cos(2n+3)x$

$\displaystyle=\cos x-\cos(2n+3)x$

Now apply $\displaystyle\cos C-\cos D=2\sin\frac{C+D}2\sin\frac{D-C}2$ to get

$\displaystyle\cos x-\cos(2n+3)x=2\sin(n+2)x\sin(n+1)x$

Comment: @bebo, how about this one?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use induction. Then in the last step you get the following:
$$
\sin(2x) + \sin(4x) + ....+ \sin(2kx) + \sin(2(k+1)x)\\
=\frac{\sin(kx)\sin((k+1)x) + \sin(x)\sin(2(k+1)x)}{\sin(x)} \\
= \frac{-\cos{(2k+1)x}+\cos x -\cos{(2k+3)x}+\cos(2k+1)x }{2\sin(x)}\\
= \frac{\cos x -\cos{(2k+3)x} }{2\sin(x)}= \frac{\sin (k+1)x \sin{(k+2)x} }{\sin(x)}\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if it is true for $n=k$, then : 
$$    sin(2x)+sin(4x)+…+sin(2kx) +sin(2(k+1)x) = \frac{sin((k)x)sin((k+1)x)}{sin(x)} + sin(2(k+1)x)    $$
$$ =   \frac{sin((k)x)sin((k+1)x) + sin(x)\left[sin((k+1)x + (k+1)x)\right]}{sin(x)}   $$
$$ =   \frac{sin((k)x)sin((k+1)x) + 2sin(x)sin((k+1)x)cos((k+1)x)}{sin(x)}   $$
$$ =   \frac{sin((k)x)sin((k+1)x) + sin(x)\left[sin((k+1)x)cos((k+1)x)+sin((k+1)x)cos((k+1)x)\right]}{sin(x)}   $$
$$ =   \frac{sin((k+1)x)\left[sin(kx) + sin(x)cos((k+1)x)+(cos(k+1)x)sin(x))\right]}{sin(x)}   $$
Notice that $sin(kx) = sin(k+1 -1)x = (sin(k+1)x)cos(x) - (cos(k+1)x)sin(x)$
which implies $sin(kx) + (cos(k+1)x)sin(x) = (sin(k+1)x)cos(x)$. So the above term becomes : 
$$ \frac{sin((k+1)x)\left[sin((k+1)x)cos(x)+(cos(k+1)x)sin(x))\right]}{sin(x)} $$
$$ = \frac{sin((k+1)x)sin((k+2)x)}{sin(x)} $$

Comment: Identities that i used here are : $$sin(2\theta) = 2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)$$ and  $$sin(\theta_{1} + \theta_{2}) = sin(\theta_{1})cos(\theta_{2}) + sin(\theta_{2})cos(\theta_{1})$$, $$ sin(\theta_{1} - \theta_{2}) = sin(\theta_{1})cos(\theta_{2}) - sin(\theta_{2})cos(\theta_{1})  $$